# Github Pages React App index.html file not in root

Tags: html, reactjs, github, public

I have researched extensively and have not been able to find an answer to this issue. I’m thinking it might still not be solved! Is there any way to change the path of a React app (in webpack) so that the index.html file can be in the root, and not in a public folder? This would be so I can host my portfolio on github pages, which requires the index.html file to be in the root.

Comment: Yes its possible. Can you show yous webpack config?

Comment: `const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  }
};` @TheReason

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the `publicPath` as root  in output in `webpack` config file

like

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
},
```

Comment: Here is my webpack. How should I edit this? `const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  }
};`

Comment: try to add the `publicPath`  in `output` and in `devServer` as well